# Can I run a login script irrespective of the shell?

Tags: login, command-line, scripts

Is there a way to run a script on login irrespective of the shell? I would like to have something on the lines of the ssh login to an Ubuntu server - which displays the free RAM etc.

I understand that the welcome message itself is in `/etc/motd`, but the file seems to update on each login. How is this done? I do not want to use `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` and would like to have one for all users in the system by default.

Comment: What sort of login? Graphical or terminal/SSH?

Comment: Terminal Logins. I was thinking of adding a script to `/etc/profile.d/` This ececutes after the message from `/etc/motd` is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are asking for a "run for each login" versus "run at boot", this may be of help.

in the file `/etc/login.defs`
search for "fakeshell"
Here is the comment text for that parameter:

```
 # Instead of the real user shell, the program specified by this parameter
 # will be launched, although its visible name (argv[0]) will be the shell's.
 # The program may do whatever it wants (logging, additional authentification,
 # banner, ...) before running the actual shell.
 # FAKE_SHELL /bin/fakeshell
```

Be careful about any assumptions for your environment when using this approach.  Define all your own paths for executables and data.

Comment: Thank you. I added a line `FAKE_SHELL /etc/loginscript` and added a shell script with execute permissions for all. But nothing happened on login through ssh :-(

Comment: I was thinking of adding a script to `/etc/profile.d/` This executes after the message from `/etc/motd` is displayed.

Comment: Sorry that did not work.  I just re-read your request and wonder if I misunderstood.  Are trying to create a script that any user can run that gives free RAM and other system statistics?  I was trying to find an answer for the "run this script for all users when they log in".  If you want something for all  you can create a special account, call it "sysres" that has no password but instead of a shell it just runs the loginscript to display what you want, and then it exits, no interaction provided.  I will still look for a "runs for every user, every login, and style" answer.

Comment: I was wondering how ubuntu displays system statistics. Apparently, it seems to run a script to update /etc/motd and the statistics is displayed as a welcome message.

Comment: I now realize that the `FAKE SHELL` was running a script, but only at the tty and not at the pty (ssh). And running a bash script that did not transfer over to bash caused me to be logged out immediately after logging in and running the script.

Comment: Although this did not work for me at the time, I am accepting this as the answer only to improve my acceptance ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/etc/rc.local`

rc.local is executed after all other init stuff is over - the last step in the startup process. It's really intended for local machine init stuff outside of the System V init (i.e. outside of the runlevel scripts).

Comment: Should point out that this happens before any sort of graphical login; even before X has even started to load and only happens at boot (not once per login).

Answer (score 0):

I you are looking for a script that display's Ram, HDD usage, IP address then I would suggest installing landscape-common:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install landscape-common
```

Then adding an alias in .bashrc which reflects something like `alias lsi='landscape-sysinfo'` when you run it you get the following info:

```
System load:  2.7                Processes:             161
  Usage of /:   8.3% of 135.63GB   Users logged in:       1
  Memory usage: 19%                IP address for eth0:   192.168.10.5
  Swap usage:   0%                 IP address for virbr0: 192.168.122.1

Graph this data and manage this system at [landscape.canonical.com]
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I was trying to run a script before any TTY prompt showd up. Ubuntu happens to display statistics by default (from /etc/motd) and I used that as an example. I am really interested in knowing how /etc/motd is updated every time someone logs in.